# Server/client communication

Tags: java, sockets, io, ports

I got a program which listens to connections from a client.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class SocketExampleServer {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

    int port = 5665;
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("Waiting incoming connection...");

    Socket s = ss.accept();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    String x = null;

    try {
        while ((x = dis.readUTF()) != null) 
        {
        System.out.println(x);
        out.writeUTF(x.toUpperCase());

        }      

    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Client closed its connection.");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Unknown exception");
    }

    s.close();
    ss.close();
    dis.close();
    out.close();
    System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

The things is that at this point

```
 System.out.println(x);
            out.writeUTF(x.toUpperCase());
```

only the second line is executed. If you swap the line once a gain only the second line is executed. What is the reason for that?
And one more thing when I run the program second time it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at SocketExampleServer.main(SocketExampleServer.java:9)
```

Once I change the port number to a new one it runs for a one time and the next time you need to update the port number if you want to run it again. I did not get the reason for that cause I close the socket and in my opinion the port shall stay free for the next run up.

Comment: [Have look at the actual ports](http://www.petri.co.il/quickly_find_local_open_ports.htm), maybe you can see which process keeps binding the sockets.

Answer (score 1):

On the 2nd question:

Not sure what is causing that, but to avoid the possibility of a non-checked exception thrown by your code is the reason, you should close your resources in a finally clause:

```
ServerSocket ss;
try {
...
} 
finally {
    if (ss.close() != null) {
                ss.close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: No, operator finally does not change anything.

Comment: How exactly do you run your program and how do you terminate it?

Comment: First I run the server (above), then I start the client ( not introduced here). At the end of each file I have got System.exit(0);

Comment: to me it looks like your program never exits the while loop, or one of s.close() or ss.close() throws an exception, preventing the socket from being closed properly.